# Mavericks downgrade to Mountain Lion - alert cannot be installed on this computer

Tags: error, macos

I purchased a second hand iMac with Mavericks Developer installed already, seen as I am not a developer and other things don't work, I purchased a copy of Mountain Lion but when tring to run the installer it gives me this message
"alert mac os x 10.7 cannot be installed on this computer"
I want to keep all user profiles and software intact so I don't want to wipe the hard drive (although many other posts say when you get that message wiping the hard drive still doesn't solve it)

any ideas?

Comment: 10.7 is Lion, not Mountain Lion. The computer might have been made after 10.8 (Mountain Lion) was released.

Comment: I'd say backup your files and wipe it. Wiping the hard drive allows you to downgrade. I know because I've down it before (from Mavericks to Lion)

Comment: Why not just install Mavericks for free?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your iMac can run the older version of Mac OS X. You can see what versions can be run by searching for your specific model of iMac at [EveryMac](http://everymac.com)

Sometimes I have seen that even if a Mac was shipped with an older version of Mac OS it is difficult to downgrade due to firmware upgrades that make the system incompatible with older releases. I haven't personally experienced this sort of issue in maybe 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exaclty "downgrade". 
You habe to create a bootable drive with your installer, boot from that drive, reformat your internal (backup first!) and then install 10.7

Make sure your computer supports it first.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion some more infos would be great to help you:

1. What do you mean with "Mavericks Developer installed already"? Does it mean it is a beta Mavericks installation only available for developers? Or do you mean XCode is installed?
2. Why do you want to downgrade to 10.7?
3. "and other things don't work": what is not working? I do not see the connection.
4. Why do you want "to keep all user profiles and software intact"? You bought a second hand iMac, and I would expect that you would like to reset it.

A little hint for users who sell their computer: you should re-install the Mac system and remove all data before selling you computer!